# Why can we assume that $Y$ is noetherian in the proof of Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 14.121?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying Gortz's Algebraic Geometry Proposition 14.121 and stuck at understanding some reduction assumption ( please understand that it is too long to write them all down so I'll often  upload associated data as images ) :

[image]

As the underlined statement, why can we assume that $Y$ is noetherian ?

There the statement "all properties of $f$ are compatible with inductive limits of rings" maybe means as follows (c.f. his book prop.12.58 -(4)  and prop.14.4. ) :

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

And in the first above image, Theorem 10.69 is as follows :

[image]

From these, how can we show by using the Theorem 10.69 that we may assume that $Y$ is noetherian?
Things seems to be more complicated and I don't know how can we handle it to obtain our desired reductibility.

For example, how can we set 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 in the above image ( (10.13) Introduction and notation ) to deduce our goal?

How can we use the Theorem 10.69 ? In the proof of the Proposition 14.121, we may assume that $Y=\operatorname{Spec}R$ is affine. And apply the theorem 10.69 to the morphism $f : X \to \operatorname{Spec}R$?

Can anyone help?

My first attempt

: Apply the Thm. 10.69 to $f : X \to Y := \operatorname{Spec}R$ and $\operatorname{id}_R : \operatorname{Spec}R \to \operatorname{Spec}R$.
Then there exist a noetherian ring $R_0$, schemes $X_0$ and $Y_0$ of finite type over $R_0$, a morphism $f_0 : X_0 \to Y_0$ of $R_0$-schemes, and a ring homomorphism $R_0 \to R$, such that $X \cong X_0 \otimes_{R_0} R , Y \cong Y_0 \otimes_{R_0} R$, and $f = f_0 \otimes \operatorname{id}_R$.

In the above image, (10.13) Introduction and notation, set

1. $\Lambda : = \{ 0, 1\}$. And let $R_1 : = R$.
2. Transition map $\sigma_{01} : R_0 \to R_1 := R$ is the above ring homomorphism.
   $S_0 := \operatorname{Spec}R_0, S_1 : = \operatorname{Spec}R_1 = \operatorname{Spec}R$. $s_{o1} : S_1 \to S_0$.

3, 5.  $X_0 ,Y_0$ : $S_0 := \operatorname{Spec}R_0$ -schemes (of finite type).

$ X_1 := X_0 \times_{S_{0}} S_1 = X_0 \times_{R_0} R \cong X$, $ Y_1 := Y_0 \times_{S_{0}} S_1 = Y_0 \times_{R_0} R \cong Y$.

$x_{01} : X\cong X_1 \to X_0$, $y_{01}:Y \cong Y_1 \to Y_0 $.

6. $f_0 : X_0 \to Y_0 $ : the above morphism of $S_0$-schmes

   $f_1 : X_1 \to Y_1 $ : the morphism obtained by base change.

   Question :  $f_1 = f_0 \otimes \operatorname{id}_R = f$ ?

Then since $f$ is of finite presentation, since being proper and flat is compatiable with inductive limits of rings (as in the above image, Proposition 12.58, Proposition 14.4), maybe, $f_0$ is proper and flat (even further of finite presentation?)

And this is a point that I stuck. Can we show from these that we may assume that $Y$ is noetherian? If so, how? Am I going to right direction?

Can anyone help?